# Como Fazer um Update no Banco de Dados Mysql com Cache

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, servidor, plugin-wordpress

Tenho um plugin wordpress de posts relacionados, Eu tenho uma tabela onde eu atualizo o número de cliques e o numero de visualizaçoes de cada post! O problema é, em sites grandes eu estou derrubando servidores com tantos updates no banco, já que eu faço isso a cada visita e a cada clique!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa imagem mostra o plugin fazendo o update no banco a cada visita!

Existe uma forma de reduzir essas querys? Com cache talvez, mas eu não sei como fazer.

Comment: Você pode guardar essas informações em um bloco de texto e depois subir no banco de uma vez.

Comment: Como implementar isso vai depender muito da estrutura da sua aplicação e da estratégia pra uso desses dados. Por exemplo, se você tem como registrar esses cliques num BD externo, separado da sua aplicação e dedicado pra isso, em teoria isso pode resolver. Se isso não for possível você precisa implementar uma rotina assíncrona, colocando esses requests em filas pra serem executadas quando o servidor estiver com recursos disponíveis. Senão é batata que vai derrubar o site num pico de acessos.